# API Gateway: Empty request body?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, post, sdk, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to send a **POST body** to a **AWS Lambda** function using the **iOS (Swift) SDK** generated by **AWS API GATEWAY**, but the transmitted body is always empty.

To do so I set up a model:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "InputModel",
    "type": "object",
    "required" : ["name"],
    "properties": {
        "name": { "type": "string" },
    }
}
```

,which I included in the *$Resources -> /test -> POST -> Method Execution -> Method Request -> Request Body* panel.

Then I deployed the API and downloaded and included the API Gateway generated SDK. Now I am calling the API (as recommended in [Use Generated iOS SDK (Swift) to Call API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-ios-swift.html)) like so:

```
let apiClient = APITestClient.default()
let body = APITest()
body!.name = "HOLA"

apiClient.testPost(body: body!).continueWith { task -> Void in ... }
```

But the **body** my Lambda function receives is always empty `{}`, which I checked in the **API Gateway** logs:

```
(c421a895-b0c7-11e7-89a6-891dcbadf1f0) Method request body before transformations:
{}
```

and the **Lambda function** Logs:

```
2017-10-14T10:09:29.418Z    c424b611-b0c7-11e7-99c1-251bdb6a1eac    Request:
{
    "resource": "/test",
    "path": "/test",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Accept-Encoding": "br, gzip, deflate",
        "Accept-Language": "en-us",
        "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
        "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": "true",
        "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false",
        "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": "false",
        "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false",
        "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "ES",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "Host": "9hlt8n48wd.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
        "User-Agent": "aws-sdk-iOS/2.6.4 iOS/11.0 en_US",
        "Via": "2.0 9ee2752d23ce7be13204dc3880c3ca6b.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
        "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "39uT89_umng7zPCNHqn3WdLlNJ6zFbQ5fmLVzJJNFcud-7pdZYJ1mg==",
        "X-AMZ-Date": "20171014T100929Z",
        "x-amz-security-token": "---",
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "---",
        "X-Forwarded-For": "---",
        "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
    },
    "queryStringParameters": null,
    "pathParameters": null,
    "stageVariables": null,
    "requestContext": {
        "path": "/production/test",
        "accountId": "037641059503",
        "resourceId": "hfza9c",
        "stage": "production",
        "requestId": "---",
        "identity": {
          ---
        },
        "resourcePath": "/test",
        "httpMethod": "POST",
        "apiId": "---"
    },
    "body": "{}",
    "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

Why is the body always empty? Do I have to initialize the body different than I do? Or is there another stage where the body is cleared?

---

**Edit:** 
I am still struggling, but invoking the normal *AWS iOS SDK*:

```
let apiClient = APITestClient.default()
let apiGatewayRequest = AWSAPIGatewayRequest(httpMethod: "POST", urlString: "/test", queryParameters: nil, headerParameters: nil, httpBody: ["name":"example"])
apiClient.invoke(apiGatewayRequest).continueWith { task -> Void in ... }
```

works perfectly fine. Why does AWS even bother with generating a special API Gateway SDK?!

---

**Edit 2: The API model**

```
public class APITest : AWSModel {

    var example: String?

    public override static func jsonKeyPathsByPropertyKey() -> [AnyHashable : Any]!{
        var params:[AnyHashable : Any] = [:]
        params["name"] = "name"

        return params
    }
}
```

which is then called by

```
   public func testPost() -> AWSTask<APITest> {
        let headerParameters = [
                   "Content-Type": "application/json",
                   "Accept": "application/json",

                ]

        let queryParameters:[String:Any] = [:]

        let pathParameters:[String:Any] = [:]

        return self.invokeHTTPRequest("POST", urlString: "/test", pathParameters: pathParameters, queryParameters: queryParameters, headerParameters: headerParameters, body: nil, responseClass: APITest.self) as! AWSTask<APITest>
    }
```

Comment: Can you try with a mock response from API gateway integration request?

Comment: I tried, but the body is still empty. Can it be that the generated SDK is incompatible with Swift 4 from XCode 9.0?

Comment: Can you test your API endpoint with Postman or another HTTP client?

Comment: With Postman as with the API Gateway console, when I manually enter the POST body like `{ "name" : "example" }` the body is passed.

Comment: @Knowledge What do you see in your API Gateway Models?

Comment: @dashmug I added the source code in the second edit. I hope you where asking for that.

Comment: @Knowledge No. What I meant is the models in API Gateway Console. Like this https://imgur.com/x9Q8uAh. Do you see your `InputModel` in that page?

Comment: @dashmug yes I can see it: https://imgur.com/a/nyFHT

Comment: @Knowledge I think it's a problem with the generated SDK. I'm not a Swift dev, so I can't help you with that. But if it works without using the generated SDK, then just do that then. Or, you can contact AWS support regarding the buggy generated SDK.

Answer (score 4):

I had to manually add the @objcMembers attribute to the generated parameters model class:

`@objcMembers
public class MyParamsModel : AWSModel`

Answer (score 1):

The body of my request was also showing as empty, I needed to include:

```
Content-Type:application/json
```

In the request header

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation you got a typo in your AWSAPIGatewayRequest,

> AWSAPIGatewayRequest(httpMethod: "POST", urlString: "/test",
>   queryParameters: nil, headerParameters: nil, HTTPBody:
>   ["name":"example"])

**Reference:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSAPIGatewayRequest.html#//api/name/initWithHTTPMethod:URLString:queryParameters:headerParameters:HTTPBody:

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

in the API Console :
[image]

if you click on integration request :

[image]

make sure that the parameters you want your lambda to consume to be specified as in the screenshot. hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mapping templates then please make sure you add "input" property and set it to request-body you want to send in string format.

```
{
"input": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$'))"
}
```

Same issue I was facing when I was trying to set input request body from apigateway to step function and when I set up as per AWS docs(like you are trying above) it always sent empty request body. but when I set request body in "input" property, it was sent to request body in JSON format to my step function.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that AWS only sends requests using "Content-Type: text/plain", and it worked here ;)